# How can i remove temp table after creating it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi How can i remove temp table after creating it

because i get this error `There is already an object named '#tmp_statement' in the database.`

```
SELECT * FROM #tmp_statement
DROP TABLE #tmp_statement
```

Comment: What happens when you try to drop it?

Comment: There is already an object named '#tmp_statement' in the database.

Comment: this is not when dropping it. just run `drop` statement only and then comment drop statement and run your code. you will not get any error.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error on creating it, not when dropping it. Try putting this before creating table:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#tmp_statement') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp_statement
```

Or just put it before any other statements you have.